# simplify $x^4-3x^2+2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

simplify $x^4-3x^2+2=0$

for some reason I am getting stuck. the discriminant equals 1 which is a perfect square so it can be factored, but I couldn't get it down. If I factor it I get $\pm 1$ and $\pm 2$ but the answer stays $\pm 1$ or $\pm\sqrt2$

When I tried to do the quadratic formula I got $2$ or $1$. help.

Comment: Well, since there is $x^4$ and $x^2$ I would suggest substitution $x^2 = y$.

Comment: 2 isn't a 6solution as 16-12+2=6 not 0. If one puts in the square root of 2, then the left hand side becomes 4-6+2=0 which is correct.

Answer (score 4):

A basic hint would be to assume $x^2=X$ and then $$x^4-3x^2+2=0\to X^2-3X+2=0$$ Now, we have then $X^2-3X+2=0$. Remember when you have $ax^2+bx+c=0$ while $a+b+c=0$ then one root is $+1$ and the other is $c/a$. So we get $$X=1,~~X=2$$ So $x^2=1$ and $x^2=2$.

Comment: so by doing that, am I then squaring the 2 and 1 at the end of it?  is that how I would/could get $\sqrt2$?

Comment: @Joshhw: I added some points.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the $-3x^2$ into $-x^2-2x^2$, this is quite simple:

$x^4-3x^2+2=x^4-x^2-2x^2+2=x^2(x^2-1)-2(x^2-1)=(x^2-1)(x^2-2)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2)$

Were you stopping at $(x^2-1)(x^2-2)$? The original equation is a quartic not a quadratic. The problem isn't $x^2-3x+2=0$ though it looks like that.

Comment: I was stopping at that. is that $\sqrt2$ because the $(x^2-2)$ could be a diff of two squares if the 2 is treated as a $\sqrt2$?

Comment: Yes, it is treating 2 as a square with $\sqrt2$ as the root.